# Is there a way to merge snippets or make a disjoint snippet in Doxygen?

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen, code-snippets, manual

I would really like to use the `\snippet` function in the manual of my code, since it would embody DRY. However, part of my manual shows a user how to build up an example use case piece by piece for which I would need to include a disjoint snippets with my own code inserted in between. Something like:

Original code:

```
#include <A.h>
#include <B.h>
#include <C.h>

MyClass:MyClass(const std::string& name)
     : BObj_(name)
{
   AObj_.setReadyForAction();

   AObj_.deactivateSwitching();
}
```

I would like to include it in my manual as

```
#include <A.h>
...

MyClass:MyClass(const std::string& name)
     : AObj_(name)
{
   AObj_.setReadyForAction();

   ...
}
```

This would be three snippets (or two if one discounts the closing brace) merged with `...`'s inbetween.

I could live without the `...`'s, and so could also just see this is a single disjoint snippet.

Is it possible to merge snippets? Is it possible to define a disjoint snippet? Alternatively, is there any way I could include pieces of code just by reference to a line number in the file rather than using defined snippet markers?

Comment: You mentioned already something about "include pieces of code just by reference to a line number in the file", did you have look at \dontinclude and the command mentioned there?